# How to mathematically determine if the magnitude of a cross product is up/down(positive/negative?)?

Tags: linear-algebra, physics, mathematical-physics, vectors

So, I'm a newbie at complex vector math. I'm working on a 2D physics engine, and my issue is, with angular acceleration from torque, is it supposed to be positive or negative? I understand the right hand rule vaguely, but not how it translates into math. A google search didn't yield anything, and I'm quite clueless.

Comment: An upward (positive) angular acceleration is the result of a torque applied counterclockwise.

Comment: Well the sign of the cross product is determined by $ sin (\theta) $ where $\theta $ is the angle between vectors. And the sign of the torque is determed by the exact same thing.

Comment: @dylan7 Which two vectors? The lever arm and the normal vector or?

Comment: @user3618509: the lever arm and the applied force. $\tau=||F||*||r||*sin (\theta) $. Where $\tau $ is torque and $ r$ is the lever arm length. You can also use the right-hand rule as Omnomnomnom explained, which I personally like better. But the math way is what I said.

Comment: The right hand rule doesn't work in computer code(they don't have hands, and more importantly, the ability to interpret them easily. :P), however, I'm confused by your answer. I have the torque, but I don't know if it's positive or negative.

Comment: @user3618509 as suggested in Phonon's answer, torque is a _vector_ quantity; it can't be positive or negative per se.  You can speak about the sign of its components (or, for instance, you can ask 'will this work 'for' or 'against' the body's current angular momentum, i.e. is $\tau\cdot L$ greater than or less than zero), but you can't say whether torque itself is positive or negative.

Answer (score 0):

If you are computing everything component-wise (meaning you need to have defined an orthonormal basis {$\hat{x},\hat{y},\hat{z}$}), as shown below (taken from [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Right-HandedCoordinateSystem.html)):

[image]

remains to just perform the cross product of the force $\mathbf{F}$ and $\mathbf{r}$ of your object, meaning: 
$$\mathbf{F}\times \mathbf{r} =(F_y r_z-F_z r_y)\hat{x}+(F_z r_x-F_x r_z)\hat{y}+(F_x r_y -F_y r_x)\hat{z} $$

Which is the torque vector with the above components.